# How to set Wordpress and index.php to WP site

Tags: wordpress

I have a running website and now i like to use WP for a couple of sub website/pages. So i am installing WP in subfolder, but now i am a bit clueless how to set up my index.html and .htaccess

I guess i need to make index.html to index.php so i can add

```
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

but that would load WP and not my running website.

Any advice on how to be able to run these URI as WP pages

mydomain.com/example-1
mydomain.com/example-2
mydomain.com/wpwebsite

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install WordPress in your subfolder, maybe /wordpress/, then you can change the index.php in your /wordpress/ folder from:

```
require('./wp-blog-header.php');
```

to:

```
require('./wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

move index.php and .htaccess from your /wordpress/ folder to your main folder, now you should be able to change the pages. The other pages you would like to add without WordPress:

Create .php / .html files and put it in the main folder, these should be available, if you call the url of the .php / .html file.

The best way is to use WordPress for all your pages.